# Java String.split not work

Tags: java, string, split

I am using Java programming language and I have problem.

```java
String val = "1 - v2";
val = val.split(val,' ')[0];
System.out.println("Value of val is: " + val);
```

Output:

```
>>> Value of val is:
```

I use similar code a few lines further and works there without any problems.

Where I make mistakes?

// Thx

Comment: Please read the javadoc of `split`.

Comment: *I use similar code a few lines further and works there without any problems.* - Well, then show us that code. I suspect it would work that way anywhere.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is the result you expect?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Now I have found it.

Comment: Do you realise that `split(val,' ')` invokes `split(String regex, int limit)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split it by space try,

```
val = val.split("\\s")[0];
```

Here the String is split by `whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")`

Answer (score 0):

Read the method definitions:

```
String[] java.lang.String.split(String regex)
String[] java.lang.String.split(String regex, int limit)
```

It expects a regex expression, and optionally a integer representing the limit. You are passing the following to the method:

```
split(val, ' ')
```

the second argument is a character, not an integer.

If you want to split by a space:

```
val.split(" ")
```

or if you want to split by any whitespace:

```
val.split("\\s")
```